# Ending blocked GUI threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, crash-reports

I am writing a platform game in java.  I am making it so that when an exception occurs in the game it will show the user an error report.  However, it is causing problems when an error occurs in a gui thread, because then the error report wont show because the gui is blocked.

How would I safely do this?  I tried safely ending all of the blocking gui threads, but then it gave me an error saying that the thread was interrupted.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that illustrates the problem you encountered and the corresponding stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) , so that the UI thread is not blocked. It should be used when doing a long running task in the background without freezing UI.

Comment: but the problem is that my gui thread is crashing becuase of an exception

Comment: the code which is causing the exception should be in the background thread I think, to handle it properly

Comment: but what if the exception is a runtime exception so it is undetected or if it originates from another thread

Comment: Event dispatch thread should not be having such code which may have even runtime exception, if it is from any other thread then it will not block UI, I think